# For what values of p does the integral converge

Tags: calculus

For what values of p does the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^p}$ converge? I know that I should probably use the comparison test for integrals somehow but I don't know what function to compare it to.

Comment: For start, what comparison test did you have in mind? Do you know to solve the problem for some values of $p$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: try first to see where and why the integral is improper and then for which $p$ it converges, in comparison with Riemann integrals.

Comment: I know it's improper at x=0 but can you elaborate more on how to determine for which p it converges?

Comment: Good, but not only that, an integral is always improper at $\pm \infty$ because it is the limit of $\int_a^b$ when the bounds tend to infinity. Fortunately, what can we say of the integrand for big $x$? Are you familiar with the convergence of $\int_0^1x^{-a}$?